# Слайдинг за пределы viewpager

Tags: android-viewpager, android

Возможно ли реализовать слайдинг за пределы viewpager по бокам, как, к примеру, в listview, только listview он сверху и снизу.

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
viewPager.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
```

Или же, вы можете сделать то же самое, добавив в XML-layout следующий атрибут для `ViewPager`:

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

Доступно на API 9 и выше.

Comment: Возможно, я делаю что-то не так, но у меня не оттягивается с этим атрибутом. сам код viewpager'a в первый пост добавил

Comment: Отдельные вендоры любят overscroll у себя отключать, например, неоднократно замечал такое на девайсах Samsung и HTC.

Comment: кстати, да, запускаю программу на HTC. Наверное в этом проблема

Comment: Можете попробовать ещё добавить `android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"`.

Comment: Тоже не помогает